# Trying to run two double for loops

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, arraylist

So I have two array lists:

```
ArrayList<String> name = getNames();
ArrayList<String> comment = getComments();
```

And I have an object named feedback which contains two parameters: name and comment to which I'm storing all the names and comments existing in the arraylists mentioned above.

```
ArrayList<feedback> fb = new ArrayList<feedback>();

    for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<comment.size();j++)
      {
         feedback f = new feedback();
         f.name = name.get(i).toString();
         f.comment = comment.get(j).toString();
         fb.add(f);
      }
    }
```

What I want is to store these names and comments in order respectively such that the first name will be assigned the first comment. Instead what I get is every name being assigned to every comment.

What I want:

**For example:**

```
Bill added a comment: "Hey"
Jerry added a comment: "Oops"

So there should be 2 feedback objects:

Name = Bill
Comment = "Hey"

Name = "Jerry"
Comment: "Oops"
```

My loop is obviously wrong. What changes should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a single loop :

```
for(int i=0;i<name.size() && i < comment.size();i++) {
     feedback f = new feedback();
     f.name = name.get(i);
     f.comment = comment.get(i);
     fb.add(f);
}
```